# Faster C# (or other .NET) Levenshtein distance implementation

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, performance, levenshtein-distance

Good night,

I have been working with fuzzy string matching for some time now, and using C with some pointers I could write a very fast (for my needs) implementation of the Levenshtein distance between two strings. I tried to port the code to C# using unsafe code and the `fixed` keyword, but the performance was way slower. So I chose to build a C++ dll and use `[DllImport]` from C#, automatically marshalling every string. The problem is that, after profiling, this keeps being the most time-consuming part of my program, taking between 50-57% of the total running time of the program. Since I think I will need to do some heavy work with lots of substrings of a text field coming from some 3-million database records, I think the time the Levenshtein distance is taking is almost unacceptable. That being, I would like to know if you have any suggestions, both algorithmic or programming-related, to the code below, or if you know of any better algorithm to calculate this distance?

```
#define Inicio1  (*(BufferVar))
#define Inicio2  (*(BufferVar+1))
#define Fim1  (*(BufferVar+2))
#define Fim2  (*(BufferVar+3))
#define IndLinha (*(BufferVar+4))
#define IndCol  (*(BufferVar+5))
#define CompLinha (*(BufferVar+6))
#define TamTmp  (*(BufferVar+7))

int __DistanciaEdicao (char * Termo1, char * Termo2, int TamTermo1, int TamTermo2, int * BufferTab, int * BufferVar)
{
 *(BufferVar) = *(BufferVar + 1) = 0;
    *(BufferVar + 2) = TamTermo1 - 1;
    *(BufferVar + 3) = TamTermo2 - 1;

 while ((Inicio1 <= *(BufferVar + 2)) && (Inicio2 <= *(BufferVar + 3)) && *(Termo1 + Inicio1) == *(Termo2 + Inicio2))
  Inicio1 = ++Inicio2;

  if (Inicio2 > Fim2) return (Fim1 - Inicio1 + 1);

 while ((Fim1 >= 0) && (Fim2 >= 0) && *(Termo1 + Fim1) == *(Termo2 + Fim2))
  { Fim1--; Fim2--;}

  if (Inicio2 > Fim2) return (Fim1 - Inicio1 + 1);

 TamTermo1 = Fim1 - Inicio1 + 1;
 TamTermo2 = Fim2 - Inicio2 + 1;
 CompLinha = ((TamTermo1 > TamTermo2) ? TamTermo1 : TamTermo2) + 1;

 for (IndLinha = 0; IndLinha <= TamTermo2; *(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha) = IndLinha++);
 for (IndCol = 0; IndCol <= TamTermo1; *(BufferTab + IndCol) = IndCol++);

 for (IndCol = 1; IndCol <= TamTermo1; IndCol++)
  for (IndLinha = 1; IndLinha <= TamTermo2; IndLinha++)
   *(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + IndCol) = ((*(Termo1 + (IndCol + Inicio1 - 1)) == *(Termo2 + (IndLinha + Inicio2 - 1))) ? *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1)) : ((*(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + IndCol) < *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1))) ? ((*(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) < *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + IndCol)) ? *(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) : *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + IndCol)) : ((*(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) < *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1))) ? *(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) : *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1)))) + 1);

 return *(BufferTab + CompLinha * TamTermo2 + TamTermo1);
}
```

Please note that BufferVar and BufferTab are two external `int *` (in th case, `int[]` variables being marshalled from C#) which I do not instantiate in every function call to make the whole process faster. Still, this code is pretty slow for my needs. Can anyone please give me some suggestions, or, if possible, provide some better code?

**Edit:** The distance can't be bounded, I need the actual distance.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Are you sure that you need the Levenshtein distance between **every** pair of words? That's **9,000,000,000,000** distances if you consider every pair. Do you really need to calculate all of them? Where and how will you store the results? Could it be sufficient just to calculate the top 3 closest matches for each word, for example? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: It's not the distance between every pair of words out of those 160000. It's the actual distance between every possible pair of words a user can input. I've already corrected it.

Comment: Does your profiling indicate any lines that are particularly time intensive?

Comment: Yes... The one inside the two `for` cycles, which already includes an inlined `min(a,b,c)` function...

Comment: This will be the highest percentage time-user in your program if there's nothing much else going on. High percentage is not a bad thing, as long as it's as optimal as you can make it. What high percentage is useful for is helping you find code that you can speed up, if there is any.

Comment: Also that inner-loop line is extremely long and unreadable, as it stands.

Comment: Short code != fast code.

Comment: @Miguel: your code is very difficult to understand because of the use of non-english names for variables :/ I'm sorry but I don't recognize the words here and it really hampers my ability to decipher what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Brute Force**

Here is an implementation of the Levenshtein Distance in Python.

```
def levenshtein_matrix(lhs, rhs):
  def move(index): return (index+1)%2

  m = len(lhs)
  n = len(rhs)

  states = [range(n+1), [0,]*(n+1)]

  previous = 0
  current = 1

  for i in range(1, m+1):
    states[current][0] = i

    for j in range(1,n+1):
      add = states[current][j-1] + 1
      sub = states[previous][j] + 1
      repl = states[previous][j-1] + abs(cmp(lhs[i-1], rhs[j-1]))

      states[current][j] = min( repl, min(add,sub) )

    previous = move(previous)
    current = move(current)

  return states[previous][n]
```

It's the typical dynamic programming algorithm, just taking advantage that since one only need the last row, keeping only two rows at a time is sufficient.

For a C++ implementation, you might look at [LLVM's one](http://llvm.org/doxygen/StringRef_8cpp_source.html) (line 70-130), note the use of a stack allocated array of fixed size, replaced only when necessary by a dynamically allocated array.

I just can't follow up your code to try and diagnose it... so let's change the angle of attack. Instead of micro-optimizing the distance, we'll change the algorithm altogether.

**2. Doing better: using a Dictionary**

One of the issue you face is that you could do much better.

The first remark is that the distance is symmetric, though it doesn't change the overall complexity it will halve the time necessary.

The second is that since you actually have a dictionary of known words, you can build on that: "actor" and "actual" share a common prefix ("act") and thus you need not recompute the first stages.

This can be exploited using a Trie (or any other sorted structure) to store your words. Next you will take one word, and compute its distance relatively to all of the words stored in the dictionary, taking advantage of the prefixes.

Let's take an example `dic = ["actor", "actual", "addict", "atchoum"]` and we want to compute the distance for `word = "atchoum"` (we remove it from the dictionary at this point)

1. Initialize the matrix for the word "atchoum": `matrix = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]`
2. Pick the next word "actor"
3. Prefix = "a", matrix = `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`
4. Prefix = "ac", matrix = `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`
5. Prefix = "act", matrix = `[[..], [..], [..], [..]]`
6. Continue until "actor", you have your distance
7. Pick the next word "actual", rewind the matrix until the prefix is a prefix of our word, here up to "act"
8. Prefix = "actu", matrix = `[[..], [..], [..], [..], [..]]`
9. Continue until "actual"
10. Continue for the other words

What's important here is the rewind step, by preserving the computation done for the previous word, with which you share a good-length prefix, you effectively save a lot of work.

Note that this is trivially implemented with a simple stack and does not require any recursive call.

Answer (score 4):

Try the simple approach first - don't use pointers and unsafe code - just code plain ordinary C#... but use the correct algorithm.

There is a simple and efficient algorithm on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance) that uses dynamic programming and runs O(n*m) where n and m  are the lengths of the inputs. I suggest you try implementing that algorithm first, as it is described there and only start optimizing it after you've implemented it, measured the performance and found it to be insufficient.

See also the section [**Possible improvements**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Possible_improvements) where it says:

> By examining diagonals instead of rows, and by using lazy evaluation, we can find the Levenshtein distance in O(m (1 + d)) time (where d is the Levenshtein distance), which is much faster than the regular dynamic programming algorithm if the distance is small

If I had to guess where the problem is I'd probably start by looking at this line that runs inside **two** loops:

`*(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + IndCol) = ((*(Termo1 + (IndCol + Inicio1 - 1)) == *(Termo2 + (IndLinha + Inicio2 - 1))) ? *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1)) : ((*(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + IndCol) < *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1))) ? ((*(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) < *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + IndCol)) ? *(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) : *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + IndCol)) : ((*(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) < *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1))) ? *(BufferTab + CompLinha * IndLinha + (IndCol - 1)) : *(BufferTab + CompLinha * (IndLinha - 1) + (IndCol - 1)))) + 1);`

There appears to be a **lot** of duplication there though it's hard for me to spot exactly what's going on. Could you factor some of that out? And you *definitely* need to make it more readable.

Comment: Yes, I did try it and it was slower. No premature optimization here. I tried several different implementations in C and C#, and this one was the best I could get/find.

Comment: @Miguel: It could be that you implemented it incorrectly or didn't use the correct dynamic programming technique. Can you please post the code you tried? I'm sure it can be made more efficient. And please translate it to English... it's hard to understand what's going on when the variable names are unreadable.

Comment: @Miguel: 1) The C# code should in principle be pretty good, so if you single-step it at the instruction level, you will probably find it doing something that you can make it not have to do. Just measuring is not a good way to go at this. 2) It's better not to downvote unless the answer is simply not an honest attempt.

Comment: The downvote was because Mark said that it looked like premature optimization without first asking... And anyway, I told in the post that I had already tried several different implementations.

Comment: @Miguel: 1) I give very few downvotes, because people are trying to help, and that's a nice attitude to have on SO. 2) When it comes to performance, some people have a lot of wisdom. That doesn't mean they're always right, but it does mean they are worth listening to.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much Mark. I have corrected my vote. This algorithm is precisely the one in Wikipedia. That line translates as `if (s[i] == t[j]) return d[i-1,j-1] else return min ( ... ) + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't try all your possible words with the Levenshtein distance algortihm. You should use another faster metric to filter out the likely candidates and only on then use the Levenshtein to remove ambiguity. The first sieve can be based on a n-gram (trigram works often well) frequency histogram or a hash function.